# Weird graphical glitch in Photos (apps)

Tags: release-loki

I installed eOS Loki and i have notice that there is a weird graphic glitch around the image in photos apps. It only occur when i try to zoom in/out or when i change to another image that doesn't have the same resolution with the image before.

My laptop configuration:
AMD a8-6410,
AMD Radeon R5 + Radeon HD8570M (Using padoka ppa-happen in stock driver & this PPA),
8GB DDR3 Ram[image]

Comment: Hmm, i check up and it is gtk theme that messed up the photos apps.

Comment: This is reported as a GTK/theme bug: https://github.com/horst3180/arc-theme/issues/681

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely because of an elementary OS / Photos specific GTK styling snippet missing in your 3rd party theme. (So not an elementary OS or Photos issue but a theme issue.) I had the same issue and solved it as following:
 Copy this snippet into your theme: /.themes (or usr/share/themes) > *your theme* > GTK-3.18 (or just GTK-3 if there is no version specific folder) > gtk.css AND gtk-dark.css.
I put it after the first closing winged bracket.

... }

```
/**********
 * Photos *
 *********/

.checkerboard-layout {
    background-color: #383e41;
    background-image:
        linear-gradient(
            45deg,
            alpha (
                #000,
                0.1
            ) 25%,
            transparent 25%,
            transparent 75%,
            alpha (
                #000,
                0.1
            ) 75%,
            alpha (
                #000,
                0.1
            )
        ),
        linear-gradient(
            45deg,
            alpha (
                #000,
                0.1
            ) 25%,
            transparent 25%,
            transparent 75%,
            alpha (
                #000,
                0.1
            ) 75%,
            alpha (
                #000,
                0.1
            )
        );
    background-size: 24px 24px;
    background-position: 0 0, 12px 12px;
}

.checkboard-layout .item {
    background-color: #eee;
}

/* end Photos snippet */
```