# OSX Theme for elementary OS

Tags: release-loki, themes

I like to theme elementary OS loki but i can't find some icons, plank and wingpanel that is similar to OSX sierra. Where should i find it?

elementary OS is beautiful by itself but i'd like to try out some new theme so if its ok, can anyone help me? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

[image]

I made a light and mac-ish theme that also targets some elementary OS specific features that are not so well supported in other themes (and no need to mess around with your GTK Version as this works under GTK+ 3.18.x)

- correct elementary OS specific and adaptive Wingpanel behaviour: dark transparent background with light and/or noisy wallpapers, fully transparent with dark and clean wallpapers, solid black with maximized windows.
- corrected a graphic glitch with 3rd party themes in Photos by inserting the code from the og elementary theme from apps.css to GTK-3.18/gtk.css  (.checkerboard-layout) (this issue here [Weird graphical glitch in Photos (apps)](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/8699/weird-graphical-glitch-in-photos-apps) )
- changed transparency of Wingpanel from alpha 0.5 to 0.3 (readability is still there and it blends a little bit nicer with your wallpaper IMO).
- reduced header-bar button padding (spacing)

Issues (any help or hints appreciated):

- Level-bar for drive capacity in Files sidebar now "almost" works. Background/border missing. - Please help? Where to tinker?

Check it out here: LINK: http://fav.me/dbh88n2 < LINK

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Well, there IS (and was before) a link in the last line of my answer. I marked it as LINK left and right now. What other "essential" parts of the answer to the question "Where to find OSXish themes?" are missing in your opinion?
PS: Updated image link too.

Comment: Did you create a new one for Juno as well? @wefunkster

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this youtube tutorial covers exactly what you want :)
[TUTORIAL](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yfq_mQc8W_4)

Comment: Thank you sir for your reply, where can i get the exact osx icons that the same as osx elcapitan/sierra?

Comment: In comments, author updates the link: https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1148695/

Comment: I can't open the website you gave but does it look like this?

Comment: https://www.sketchappsources.com/resources/source-image/osx-el-capitan-icons.jpg

Comment: I can't open your link :)

Comment: K, I see it now, it looks similar to this

Comment: I see your link, it looks great! i already installed it, but are there still any icon theme that look exactly like the one in osx? not similar but exact? Thank you

Comment: I don't know the exact link, but I'm pretty sure that there is sth like that. Try searching for example noobslab :http://www.noobslab.com/2016/04/macbuntu-1604-transformation-pack-for.html?m=1

Comment: You might want to describe the steps of the solution not only linking a video.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Your all needs the link below to make your Elementary looks like Sierra:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=um2WqTUwN78

Instructions can be found in details that places the bottom of the video.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.